# $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arccos\bigl(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\bigr)$?

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I'm studying Kepler's laws from Classical Mechanics, 2nd ed. Goldstein. In page 95 there is given an indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arccos\biggl(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\biggr).$$

However, when I took a look the source given in a book (A Short Table of Integrals), there is the result

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arcsin\biggl(\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\biggr).$$

Then, I tried relations of $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$, so $\arcsin(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos(x)$ and also negative argument $-\arcsin(x)=\arcsin(-x)$, but just ended up to result

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arcsin\biggl(\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\biggr)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arccos\biggl(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\biggr)+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{-\gamma}}.$$

So is there something I don't see or understand, or is there just a misprint in the book?

For the clarification, the result is used to solve this equation:

$$\varphi=\varphi_{0}-\int\frac{du}{ \sqrt{\frac{2mE}{l^2}+\frac{2mku}{l^2}-u^2}}$$

and the book ends up to result

$$\varphi=\varphi'-\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)$$

and by solving the $u=1/r$ we got final result:

$$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{mk}{l^2}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}\cdot \cos(\varphi-\varphi')\right)$$

Comment: It does not seem correct to me but why not differentiate and check? Also where did $q$ come from? What is its value?

Comment: $q$ should be equal to $\beta ^2-4 \alpha \gamma$, I think.

Comment: In the above comment $\gamma$ was assumed to be positive.

Comment: Yes, $q=\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma$. Also $\gamma=-1$.

Comment: The constant term is unimportant, at least, because indefinite integrals are only defined up to a constant anyhow.  There does seem to be a discrepancy in the signs, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert So I have understood it right? I'm asking this just to be sure so I'm not writing any rubbish in my research. Regardless of the sign, the result will be the same, only the terms of the variables are different.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $q$ is equal to $\beta ^2-4 \alpha \gamma$ otherwise the integral won't make any sense. In the integral $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}$,  the coefficient of $x^2$ plays a major role.

Assumption: $q=\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma>0$

When $\gamma <0$

$\begin{align} \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}&=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{- \gamma (-x^2-\frac{\beta}{\gamma}x-\frac{\alpha}{\gamma})}} \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{\beta^2}{4 \gamma^2}-\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}-\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\right)^2}} 
\quad \;(\because -\gamma >0) \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}{4 \gamma^2}-\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\right)^2}}\\ 
&=\frac1{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}}{2 \gamma}\right)^2-\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\right)^2}} \text{ $\quad \;$ since ${\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}>0$} \\ 
&=\frac1{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \arcsin{\left( \frac{ \frac{2 \gamma x+\beta}{2\gamma}}{\frac{\sqrt{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}}{2 |\gamma|}}\right)}+c \;\quad \left(\because \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\left|a\right|}\right)+C\right)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \arcsin{\left( -\frac{2 \gamma x+\beta}{\sqrt{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}}\right)}+c \; \quad\; (\because |\gamma|= -\gamma)\\ 
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \arcsin{\left( \frac{2 \gamma x+\beta}{\sqrt{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}}\right)}+c  \;\quad(\because \arcsin({-x}) = -\arcsin(x)) \\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arcsin\left(\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\right)+c \tag{1}\end{align}$

When $\gamma>0$

$\begin{align} \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}&=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\gamma (x^2+\frac{\beta}{\gamma}x+\frac{\alpha}{\gamma})}} \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{\gamma}} \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}}{2 \gamma}\right)^2}} \text{ $\;\quad$ since ${\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}>0$} \\ 
&= \frac1{\sqrt{\gamma}} \cosh^{-1}{\left( \frac{ \frac{2 \gamma x+\beta}{2\gamma}}{\frac{\sqrt{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}}{2 \gamma}}\right)}+c \; \quad \left(\because \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}=\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C\right)\\ 
&= \frac1{\sqrt{\gamma}} \cosh^{-1}{\left( \frac{2 \gamma x+\beta}{\sqrt{\beta^2-4 \alpha \gamma}}\right)}+c\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{\gamma}} \cosh^{-1}{\left( \frac{2 \gamma x+\beta}{\sqrt{ q}}\right)} \tag{2}\end{align}$

---

Since, in your case, $\gamma<0, \;$   $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arcsin\left(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\right)+c$$ And this result can be rewritten in terms of $\arccos()$ as $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arccos\left(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\right)+c'\tag{3}$$ where $c'=c+{ \pi\over 2 \sqrt{-\gamma}}$

Clearly, $(3)$ and $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arccos\left(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\right) \tag4$$ don't just differ by a constant.

So, you are right, that is a misprint.

**Edit:** Proceeding with $(3)$ we get,

$\begin{align} &\int\frac{du}{ \sqrt{\frac{2mE}{l^2}+\frac{2mku}{l^2}-u^2}}=-\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)\\
\therefore  & \; \:\varphi=\varphi'+\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)\\
\implies & \cos(\varphi-\varphi')=\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\\
\implies &\frac{1}{r}=u=\frac{mk}{l^2}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}\cdot \cos(\varphi-\varphi')\right)\end{align}$

which is same as the final result.

It can be noticed that it doesn't matter if $\varphi=\varphi'+\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)$ or $\varphi=\varphi'-\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)$, the final result would be same since $\cos(\varphi-\varphi')=\cos(\varphi'-\varphi)$

Comment: When $\gamma<0$, isn't $\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arcsin\bigg(\dfrac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{q}}\bigg)$? (Where $q=\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma$). In my case $\gamma<0$.

Comment: @MattiHokkanen Sorry for the mistake. Yes, you are right, the printed integration is wrong indeed, but it's a coincidence that, even with the wrong result, the final equation of orbit is correct. However, the equation which leads to the final result is this:  $\varphi=\varphi'+\arccos\left(\frac{\frac{l^2u}{mk}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2El^2}{mk^2}}}\right)$. I hope this makes sense, after all $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ are two constants of integration. Aren't they?

Comment: Yes, they are! Huge thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma<0$, the integral is equal to:

$-\frac{tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{2\gamma.x+\beta}{2\sqrt{-\gamma}.\sqrt{\gamma.x^{2}+\beta.x+\alpha}}\Big)}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}$